# Combine date range in column A row 3 though 9 and repeat every 7 rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet where I need to take an average cost of 7 days.  I have two columns, one with a date and the other with a charge. See the attached screenshot for reference and output. The formula I'm using for charges works as expected in column d. I need to find a way to add the date range in column c. Please advise

Date: Need help here - Column c should repeat, and the next cell should have 2022-08-02 and 2022-14-02. The current formula starts on 2022-02-02 if I drag the cell.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you on excel or google sheet? Screenshot seems from google-sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Try below formula to google-sheet.

```
=INDEX(TEXT(A2+SEQUENCE(10,1,0,7),"yyyy-dd-mm") & " " & TEXT(A2+SEQUENCE(10,1,6,7),"yyyy-dd-mm"))
```

For ***Excel-365*** no need `INDEX()`.

```
=TEXT(A2+SEQUENCE(10,1,0,7),"yyyy-dd-mm") & " " & TEXT(A2+SEQUENCE(10,1,6,7),"yyyy-dd-mm")
```

[image]